# Astral Gate Vulnerability in Cowboy Bebop

Tags: anime, cowboy-bebop

I'm a bit confused about the ending of episode 14 (Bohemian Rhapsody) of Cowboy Bebop. In the final scene with the gate corp executives, it is implied that the 'vulnerability' in the gates was not merely an oversight but rather something intentional. When I first watched the episode I assumed they were referring to whatever the thieves used to siphon money from gate users. That wouldn't make any sense though, what possible advantage could there be for gate corp in stealing from their customers when all they have to do is raise the tolls? Is the vulnerability something else then?

P.S. If the answer is something that gets clarified in later episodes, just let me know that and avoid spoilers. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partially explained/implied later on in the series, so spoilers ahead:

> The Vulnerabilities in the Astral Gate System 50 years earlier is later explained to have resulted in the Gate Explosion that cracks the moon and turns Earth into a giant asteroid crash pad. Chessmaster Hex had warned them and wanted to delay to run more tests, but they went ahead in launching the program anyway. The Gate Corporation essentially knew it was Hex from the beginning. The *defects built into the gate* was willful negligence, nothing intentionally malicious.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I've been loving the series so far, so I'm glad it's not just a massive plot hole.